# Photoshop: skin color change with gradient

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient

as you can see above I have two images. I need to change women face skin color with a gradient which is on the left. Maybe you can recommend some technique to do it? The only important thing is that I need to keep all face shadows, contours and lines the same. I hope to get a similar result like with a "Color replacement tool".
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Yeah... There is a lot of tutorials how to do it with one color. But I need to use gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the gradient image is big enough to cover all the areas of skin on the photograph. You may need to scale it to the correct size.

Add a layer mask to the gradient layer, and change the blending mode to "Soft Light".  You can experiment with other blending modes later, or change the layer opacity to reduce the effect.

Select the layer mask thumbnail in the layers panel. Paint in white on the mask where you want the colour to show through. Paint in black where you want the mask to be transparent.

By the way, as a side note, I don't recommend you do this, because it looks awful. The poor woman looks like an Oompa Loompa.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the blending mode `color`.
It only  changes the color and leaves the rest intact.

[image]

Whereas `soft light` changes contrast and diesnt work with every color combination.
[image]